# Inventory Dissappeared without warning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So, I was mining in my strip mine, got off to go eat.  When I came back on, I entered the world at the world spawn, and my inventory was completely empty.  I was on a minecraft multiplayer server that I made, and I'm 100% sure no one joined to do anything to me because I looked at the log.  What is this? Does anyone know what could've happened?  (EDIT: I'm the admin and the server runs on my computer. I've changed none of the server files when this happened.  Literally all I did was log off for about 5 minutes, then get back on, and my inventory and crafting recipes reset an' I'm back at world spawn like I'm a new player to the world.)

Comment: You were not on the death screen, just at spawn? Then the only thing I could imagine would be either going into the End and back (which wouldn't explain the empty inventory) or a really severe bug that I've never heard of.

Comment: well i logged off, THEN logged back on and my stuff was GONE and my crafting recipes were reset

Comment: Have you/one of the admins edited the server and plugin config? If your crafting recipes were reset, that means that you probably lost the data linked to your UUID or something like that.

Comment: I'm the admin, and it's not just happening to me, now it's started happening to everyone on the server

Comment: but how would my files have been lost/damaged if I didn't touch them, and nobody did.  There's proof of this because it happened again yesterday.  I got off for literally 5 seconds so someone could go to sleep on the game, then logged back on, it RESET AGAIN! Also, again, I own the server files on my computer, and it runs on my computer.  It might be just miscalculations that's causing the server to carry out with a wrong action. I don't really know,  I don't really know computer science.

Answer (score 2):

It's very possible that whenever you leave the server and rejoin, then the game thinks that you restarted it. It's never happened to me on Minecraft specifically, but for me it is a very common occurence in games. A few years back I was playing a Batman game but every time I turned off my playstation or quit the game, all my data got erased. No corruption, the game just thought I was restarting.

Comment: i thought this too, but I just don't know why the game did this.

Comment: Me neither. Have you tried restarting it yourself? If not, that might help the loop to end.